# Snowflake warehouse is suspended when connecting to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to connect Power BI to the snowflake_sample_data schema on a newly created Snowflake account. Power BI is able to view the warehouses, tables, and columns, and I'm able to create relationships between them. However, when creating a visualization (or previewing data in the "Get Data" step), I am receiving the error "The warehouse SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA is suspended."

The warehouse is not suspended, as I'm able to run queries against it. Further, I executed "show warehouses;" and saw that 0 warehouses were suspended.

My default user, SYSADMIN, is able to execute queries against the warehouse.

Comment: Are you sure your warehouse is called "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA" or is that the schema name?

Comment: On a default Snowflake account SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA is a database and TPCDS_SF10TCL is a schema. Now, to view metadata (view tables, columns, etc) you don't need a warehouse running (no compute needed), but to run a SELECT query on table you may need a warehouse. So, are you really sure you have a warehouse running and you're using it?

Comment: I'm able to execute a "SELECT * FROM ____ LIMIT X;" query and view data, rather than metadata. But that's from within the Snowflake GUI. This confirms that it's running, or no?

Comment: Yes, that might use a warehouse and it should be visible under the top right context where the warehouse would show a green button (meaning it's used). On the other hand, have you followed these steps to connect to a warehouse from [Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-snowflake) ? There you need to specify the warehouse name. When you do "show warehouses" from Snowflake UI, the **name** field contains warehouse name you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this one today.  In the end, it was a permissions issue.

Can you check that this role has operate privileges on the warehouse? This is required to change the state of a warehouse, (stop, start, suspend, resume).

```
grant operate on warehouse <warehouse_name> to role <role_name>;
```